# responsive css grid for dummies

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I've coded a page using percentages in div's width settings and blocks are going too close to each other while resizing the browser's window. (Here's a screenshot).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06HJI.jpg)

So is there any tutorials or tips about responsive grid for someone not so smart as me? Will be very grateful for some useful links.
Sorry for bad English btw

Comment: You forgot the important part of responsive design: media queries. When the screen gets too small, you need to use media queries to rearrange the webpage elements so that they fit again.

Comment: I've used media queries for different resolutions and it's OK when the screen's width is exactly 768px or 1024px, but it looks bad with the different sizes, so I think the main problem is within my wrong understanding of making grid and relations among elements

Comment: You need more breakpoints than that. Phone screens are typically 320-360px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About responsive you can see w3schools documents and examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

and if you need an powerfull framework that contain responsive design use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) .

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox** was built for adaptive development.

Here's are a few straightforward examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_website
https://www (dot) codepen.io/search/pens?q=flex&limit=all&type=type-pens